# find the area of a surface of revolution about x-axis : arctanh x^2

Tags: calculus, integration, calculator

I want to calculate the area of surface of revolution about x-axis.. function is $y=f(x)=\tanh^{-1}x^2$.
And area, A=$2\pi \int_{-1}^1 f(x)\sqrt{1+f'(x)^2} dx$ and $f'(x)=\frac{2x}{1-x^2}$ and $\tanh(x)=\frac{1}{2}\ln \frac{1+x^2}{1-x^2}$. I try to calculte this one.. but not easy. Help me.

Comment: You need to work more carefully.  Your expression for $f'$ is wrong.  And your identity for $\tanh x$ is really an identity for $\tanh^{-1}x.$   Work out the square root part first and see that the integral is easy after all.

Comment: I tried this numerically (after correcting $f'(x)$) and it was found to be non-convergent in Mathematica.